# Async storage not loading new fresh data, only displays data when I reload the app

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, use-effect, asyncstorage

I am working on an app, that is similar to a Todo App. I have a Two Screen's which are `SecondScreen.js`and `FirtScreen.js`. In `SecondScreen.js` is a screen which saves the data. Then the user clicks a button, it goes to `FirstScreen.js` which is this code down below. When it goes to the `FirstScreen.js` it does not update (add the new data), but it stays the same. When I add one more time, it adds the previous that was just added. Which is one data behind.

Also, the `keys = await AsyncStorage.getAllKeys()` is missing one data, the data that is added.

Also, the `keys.pop()` is for to remove a key that I don't use but it is for updating the id.

```
  const [realData, setData] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus',() => {
    getData();
  });
  return unsubscribe;
 },[navigation]);

  const getData= async () => {
    let keys = []
    try {
      keys = await AsyncStorage.getAllKeys()
    } catch(e) {
      console.log("Fail")
    }
    let values  
    let data = []
    keys.pop()
    try {    
    values = await AsyncStorage.multiGet(keys)
  } catch(e) {    // read error  
  }  

  values.map(values => {
   let jsonData = JSON.parse(value)
    data.push({"title": jsonData.title,"date": jsonData.date, "task": jsonData.task, "id": jsonData.id}) 
  })
  setData(data)
  }
``
```

Comment: As working with AsyncStorage is tricky in real time, I'd just load all asyncStorage keys/values as the app initiates and save all of them to the app state. Then as you manipulate the data, change the values in state (and save the respective value updates to asyncstorage at the same time. But read from asyncstorage only on the app initial load. That way you can more reliably manage / predict / control data flow.

Comment: I see, can you provide code please.